# reading large files fast in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am making a program that requires a list of strings for its database so i created the list as a .txt file and am loading it into a textbox but it has proven extremly slow.. the files are 100-180mb in size and i have tried `io.file.readalltext` and `streamreader(filepath)` but neither are fast enough for these files.. i need help here.

When i used the streamreader the program never loaded and i left it for an hour.
Also using the io.file.readalltext froze visual basic all together.

Is there an easier way to load files and a much faster way of getting the strings or should i not be using a .txt file?

Streamreader Code:

```
Dim r as new streamreader(file.txt)
Textbox1.text = r.ReadToEnd
R.close
```

In response to why i thought it would work loading to a text file is when i opened it in programs like wordpad there was no issue?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be using a text file, given that you describe what you have as a “database”. Either way, though, could you add the specific code you tried, and what it did with the file?

Comment: "the files are 100-180mb in size " - why would you think that reading that much info into a textbox would even work, let alone be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

A streamreader is about as fast as you'll get.  The issue is almost certainly how you are writing it to the textbox (particularly if you are writing it line by line).  As a quick test - comment out your code that writes it to the textbox and just read the file.  I'll bet it reads FAR faster.

Comment: I am trying this now if this is indead the case how would i read the file without putting it in a textbox but keep the spead factor

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by "spread factor".  Why would anyone want that large of a file in a textbox?